# Need to save xls file as xlsx, close and then reopen it

Tags: vba, excel

I am sent an .xls file to work with in my macro. Problem with .xls files is that they can't handle the number of rows I need to run my macro. So, in order to work around it, I am trying to first save the file I am sent as a .xlsx file and then continue on with the macro as planned. Unfortunately, once I reach 
`APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN & "x")` I get an error: Object required. What is wrong with my code? Am I taking the best approach to solve my .xls problem?

```
MsgBox "Please select APPS Invoice file"
APPSInvoiceFN = Application.GetOpenFilename'

If APPSInvoiceFN = False Then ' User Pressed Cancel
    MsgBox "APPS Invoice file not selected. APPS invoice will not be updated."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN)
    On Error GoTo 0

APPSInvoiceWB.SaveAs FileFormat:=51
APPSInvoiceWB.Close savechanges:=True
APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN & "x")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `Set` keyword on the last line:

```
Set APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN & "x")
```

As far as the approach goes... this method in general should work fine to convert the format.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
APPSInvoiceWB.SaveAs FileName:= APPSInvoiceFN & "x", FileFormat:=51
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, bu as you have posted partial code, have you declared `APPSInvoiceWB`  as workbook.

`Dim APPSInvoiceWB  as Workbook`

And change this part 
`APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN & "x")`
 to 
`set APPSInvoiceWB = Workbooks.Open(APPSInvoiceFN & "x")`

You are missing `Set`, hence the error.

Also, make changes as suggested by Tim